# Как вывести информацию в браузер через Java Applet?

Tags: applet, java

Хочу вывести информацию о музыкальной композиции в браузер через Java applet. Я использую библиотеку beaglebuddy_mp3.jar для получения id3 тегов. Папка с файлами выглядит так:

```
applet
 - index.html
 - FirstApplet.class
 - beaglebuddy_mp3.jar
```

В index.html я подключаю апплет:

```
<applet code="FirstApplet.class" archive="beaglebuddy_mp3.jar" width="500" height="500"></applet>
```

FirstApplet.class содержит следующий код:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.beaglebuddy.mp3.MP3;
import com.beaglebuddy.id3.enums.PictureType;

public class FirstApplet extends Applet{
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        try {
            MP3 mp3 = new MP3("D:\\Music\\abc.mp3");
            g.drawString(mp3.getBand() +" "+mp3.getTitle(), 20, 20);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

После запуска файла index.html появляется окно с предупреждением, в котором говорится, что я запускаю приложение на свой страх и риск. Потом я нажимаю кнопку "Run", мгновенно появляется и исчезает серый квадрат. На экран ничего не выводится.

Answer (score 1):

Есть технология [LiveConnect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LiveConnect) для обмена между Java и JavaScript - пример можно [посмотреть здесь](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/applet/liveconnect-the-api-for-communication-between-java-applet-and-javascript).

P.S. Оказывается, еще есть кодеры, использующие апплеты, - 100 лет никого уже не видел :)